# theft in the office

Tags: people-management

I left my personal money in my office desk drawer locked it and went home since i was leaving the office late as a sales man and its risky out there. The office is secured with CCTV cameras inside and out with day and night security men at post.I was called the next morning on phone that thieves broke into the office through the window broke my office desk drawer and other employees so they want to find out if i had no cash in there, i told them i had money in it. Upon reaching to the office i realized my money was gone and told my operations manager about it. He told me his office was also raided and money and some equipment were stolen from him and other employers, its being two days and nobody is saying anything. What do i expect from my employer.

Comment: Sorry to read about this. Adding a region to the question may help, as it will depend in part on employment law where you work. However, I don't know of *any* regions where an employer has legal *responsibility* to care for your personal items left on their property. But they do usually have some duty of care towards you as a person, and that might extend to them assisting in some say - e.g. helping you file a police report.

Comment: I am not clear what exactly you want to expect from the employer. They are not responsible for the theft, or liable to reimburse your personal property. If all that you are missing is cash, then the chances of getting it back are equal to zero. If those were some items, maybe of sentimental value then... maybe, but as this is cash, it's gone.

Comment: Second that. Unless you have a theft insurance that covers also your workplace, it's probably all gone. And, in the latter case, do you have any proof that you had this money with you (withdrawal receipt from the same day or similar)? One more thing: Could someone have known that you put your money in your desk? In that case, make sure you have the CCTV secured before someone else does.

Comment: It could depend upon the workplace. Are you working in some sensitive organization (like [LLNV](https://www.llnl.gov/) or something related to defense) requiring some [security clearance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_clearance) ? It also depends upon the country (in France, CCTV is highly regulated)

Answer (score 10):

I would not expect anything from the employer with respect to your personal property. The employer would, however, be concerned with any company property damages or stolen during this incident. I would expect that the company would be engaging with the police to make sure that they have access to the CCTV recordings and access to possible witnesses (like the security guards).

You should follow up with the operations manager to find out the status of the police investigation and to see if any of your personal property may be covered under the company insurance policies. It may be a good idea for you to talk to the police since your personal items (money) was stolen and to also consult with your insurance company to see if you are covered at all.

Generally speaking, though, it's not a good idea to keep personal property in your office. Even if the office is secured, it's not a priority for the company to protect your property. Their focus is going to be on their property.

Answer (score 6):

> What do i expect from my employer.

Expect to eventually hear from them regarding if their insurance company will reimburse you or not. It may take some time.

They may need some additional information to help them submit their claim.

In the future - never leave money (other than a trivial amount) at work.

Comment: First, he should file a claim, or at least ask. Without a claim, insurance companies can't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

If your company was negligent, then I would think they ought to pay for your losses. For example, if the office door was unlocked during the weekend knowing that there are people around. This doesn't seem to be the case here, since there was security and people still broke in.

So normally whoever owned what was lost will have to cover the losses. Let's say you worked as a rent collector and had $10,000 collected rent that you didn't want to carry through dark streets to the bank, that would be the company's money and their loss. If it was $10,000 that you saved to buy a car, that would be your loss.

However, the company might have insurance. And the insurance might cover anything in the office, not just company property in the office. Because that is a chance, you should ask your employer if there is any insurance that would cover your personal losses. And if you encountered a lazy HR person who thinks that is too much work (which is not unusual), that's when you start a fight.